# How can I change text-align with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to change this CSS text-align. it's right but I want it to be left.

```
<div class="btn_gonder" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnform">
              <input border="0" type="image" style="height:36px;width:97px;" src="../style/images/btn_gonder.png" alt="Gönder" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton1" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1"></div>
```

**CSS AREA**

```
.select_container .btn_gonder {
    float: left;
    height: 36px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 304px;
}
```

**HTML AREA**

```
<div class="btn_gonder" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnform">
              <input border="0" type="image" style="height:36px;width:97px;" src="../style/images/btn_gonder.png" alt="Gönder" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageButton1" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1"></div>
```

**MY CODE**

I wrote this code but it's not work...
How Can i change text-align with Greasemonkey ?

```
<script>
window.onload=allign;
function allign(){
document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnform').style.text-align='left';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. `<script>` tags (or any HTML tags) cannot be used like that in a Greasemonkey script.  No variant of `<script>` is need in this case, anyway.
2. [Event handlers cannot be set that way in GM scripts](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232%3a_Event_Handlers).
3. When setting styles that way, in GM-capable browsers, you need the camel-case identifier, IE `textAlign`.
4. You probably do not need the onload, but I will presume that in this case the form is not statically loaded (or styled), but loaded (or styled) by javascript.

Putting it all together, your code would become:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", alignFormText, false);

function alignFormText () {
    var theForm = document.getElementById ('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnform')

    theForm.style.textAlign = 'left';
}
```

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help!  If that does it for you, please [mark this question answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: sorry i new here so i don't know rules :) Thx again.

Comment: No problem, and it's not a rule exactly.  It's a courtesy.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it:

```
document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnform').setAttribute("style", "text-align: left;");
```